# "ng serve" is not working properly with Angular 13.0 version

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm

I just installed  npm module, and I am now facing the issue mentioned above while using node.js 14.17.6.

I'm new to Angular and I'm having trouble finding a solution to my problem because I'm not using the latest version of the Angular CLI. Could you please help me?
Thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leoaU.png)

Comment: Not an issue with angular. An issue with permission on your local system. Look at the output message. Contact your IT department.

Comment: Could you please provide a more comprehensive explanation of what I should do?

Comment: Please try "npx ng serve".

Comment: I had a similar problem in a previous project and it was fixed with the npx prefix.

Comment: @tzztson I followed your instructions and then encountered another issue. 
Still need your help.

Comment: @E.Maggini, It is definitely not the fault of my computer.

Comment: Please show me your package.json and angular.json file.

Comment: https://ibb.co/rf3KsNF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed you're using nx.
Please use `nx serve` instead of `ng serve`.

If `nx serve` isn't working, then use `npx nx serve`.

Comment: Fantastic! It's working! Thank you so much!
But I still don't know how it works.

Comment: I also got this solution from here too. Going forward, please try harder to resolve your issues before asking questions.